# RelatedObjectDoes not exist at / User has no customer

Tags: django, django-models, e-commerce

I have a Django web app. I have a products app and an accounts app. When I register a new user on my accounts app, it successfully creates a user then it gets redirected to my home page where a bunch of products are shown (controlled by the superuser). But when I login on the http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/  using the newly created user and not the admin, when the login is successful, I am supposed to be redirected to my home page, but there's an error that says. RelatedObjectDoes not exist at /
User has no customer. I'm still new thanks!

## Here is my products/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

[My admin panel with all the models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eK6y.png)

[The customer model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwoi6.png)

## My registration view

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import RegisterForm

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(response, "register/register.html", {'form':form})
```

## Product App views.py file

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']
    #this gets all product objects in the database.
    products = Product.objects.all()
    #counts how many special offers we have by using count() function
    special_offer = Product.objects.filter(special_offer=True).count()
    #returns the average price of all the product objects that we have
    aggr = Product.objects.aggregate(average_price=Avg('price'))
    average_price = round(aggr['average_price'], 2)
    #passes the product objects as a context to be passed to a template.
    context = {'products' : products, 'special_offer' : special_offer, 'average_price' : average_price, 'cartItems' : cartItems}

    return render(request, 'store.html', context)
```

## The traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'TheApp',
 'crispy_forms',
 'register.apps.RegisterConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "\Desktop\django_projects\TheEcommerceProject\TheApp\views.py", line 13, in home
        customer = request.user.customer
      File "\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
        return func(self._wrapped, *args)
      File "\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 420, in __get__
        raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(

    Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /
    Exception Value: User has no customer.
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error, and your registration code. It sounds like your registration view is not creating or linking the customer when it creates the user.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it seems like that is the case. can u help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you want help with the registration view, then please include that view with your question.

Comment: can you add your view to the post?

Comment: I added the registration view and the product app views also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]I do this lesson too. You must be superuser(admin), and add this admin to Customers

Answer (score 0):

Hi at the first add the related_name attribute to onetoonefiled in customer model same as the below code

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'customer', null=True, blank=True)
```

Make migration and migrate then try

Comment: OK! So add all your models to the post, i will test your app

Answer (score 0):

Prob you forget to register your Customer class in admin.py file
As for me, I got this problem after I delete db with customers. The error popup when I logged into my admin account and try to view site.
I've just added profile for customer in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

i also had this problem now i soved. what is actually happening is when you create a user other that admin (SU) , we are not saving the values for the normal users/customers model . so just create an object for customer  while registering will solve this issue.
so put this code in you registration view
`Customer.objects.create(user=user, name=user.username, email=user.email)`